# google maps not showing all destination markers on map, only first and last

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a google map that displays my route correctly with all markers.
https://jsfiddle.net/az5tk8ns/17/

The destinations are hard coded in:
`destinations = ["", "durban,KZN", " ixpop,kzn"]`

I then have another function that produces an array of my addresses:

```
var addresses = [];
addresses.push('Durban, KZN');
addresses.push('izopo, KZN');`
```

I then set:

```
destinations = addresses
```

https://jsfiddle.net/az5tk8ns/19/

when doing this the map only shows the start and end destination markers, not my stop in the middle?

How can I use this method so I can pass my dynamically generated array of addresses to google maps and have it show each point in the journey?

complete google maps syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var distancearray=[];
var addresses = [];
addresses.push('Durban, KZN');
addresses.push('izopo, KZN');

warehouse='ladysmith, kwa zulu natal';


function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(-28.5710903, 26.0826083);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: chicago
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('route_map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
}
var origin = "johannesburg",
  destinations = addresses

service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

function calcRoute() {
  var waypts = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < destinations.length - 1; i++) {
    waypts.push({
      location: destinations[i],
      stopover: true
    });
  }
  var request = {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destinations[destinations.length - 1],
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var orig = document.getElementById("orig"),
        dest = document.getElementById("dest"),
        dist = document.getElementById("dist");

      orig.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address;
      dest.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].end_address;
      var total_distance = 0.0;
      for (var i = 0; i < response.routes[0].legs.length; i++) {
        total_distance += response.routes[0].legs[i].distance.value;
        distancearray.push([response.routes[0].legs[i].distance.value]);
        //alert(distancearray);
      }
      dist.value = total_distance + " meters";
    }
  });

}
  initialize();

})
```

Thanks as always,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done everything correct except that there are only two destinations in the `destinations` variable which are used as start and end. There are zero waypoints in the `directionsRequest` object in the `calcRoute()` function. 
This is the reason you are not getting any intermediate waypoints and hence no markers.

See this [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7qLLhd4/1/) where I have pushed one more location to the `addresses` variable(line number 11) and it is shown on the map correctly.

You can always do `console.log(request);` to see what request object you are passing to google.

Comment: Thanks, so it actually treats the first destination as the starting point, appreciate the help.